# php executes when "View Page Source" selected

Tags: php

I came across an interesting issue when debugging some PHP code.  The code seemed to be working well.  I had some array print_r calls which I would look at using the "View Page Source" feature in Chrome.  What I found interesting is that in looking at the source code, simply by doing so caused the script to execute as if I was looking at the actual page.  The variables in the $_GET string were firing the code.

So to my question, is there any way to disable php from executing when viewing the page source?

Comment: View source is a _browser_ option, nothing to do with PHP. If the browser does a request to get that source, then of course the PHP will run.

Comment: You can use the inspector in your browser.

Comment: [Related cross-site question](http://superuser.com/questions/243967/is-it-possible-to-change-chromes-view-source-behaviour-to-use-the-current-reque).

Answer (score 0):

*View Source* is a browser feature, that simply displays the same source code that is used to render the page. The page source is either retrieved from the browsers cache or requested from the server again. In any case, the source code retrieved by the browser results in no different request made to the server as any other pageview. And since PHP runs on the web server, you will only see PHP source code in your browser if your server is poorly configured.

In order to view the actual PHP source code you need direct file access (e.g. via FTP) or disable the PHP interpreter on the web server entirely.